# Viewing dollar sign shares over Samba on OS X?

Tags: macos, sharing, smb

I love Finder's built-in "connect to server" functionality. It's great, if not a bit hidden! (Those of you that don't know about it, right-click the Finder icon in your dock and hit Connect to Server) So I use it to connect to Windows shares on several computers; I type in the address of `smb://computername` and hit Connect, and it prompts me which shares I want to mount, and mounts them. It Just Works, as is typical of Mac.

However, I know that on Linux, you can browse a server and see the shares that end in a `$`; these, of course, are supposed to be hidden (e.g. in Windows, you wouldn't ever see them) but Linux breaks through the illusion of security (or at least privacy) and shows them all.

Unfortunately, using the Connect to Server method above, I am not able to see any dollar sign shares of my server. I know this particular server has about 20 shares ending in `$`, and yet I only see these few public shares.

[image: Select the volumes you want to mount...]

**Is there a way to configure the OS X version of Samba to show these "hidden" shares?**

Comment: Interesting sidenote: the command `smbclient -L computer -U user -W DOMAIN` (filling in 'computer', 'user', and 'DOMAIN') does indeed show all shares including those which end in a dollar sign. So it appears something differs between `smbclient` and the way in which Finder browses servers.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a way to make them show in the list, but you could just type `smb://servername/sharename$` in that box, if you know the name of the share.

In that initial Connect to Server window, you can also click the `+` icon to bookmark it in the list below the text field. That way, you don't have to type it every time.

Alternately, if you have a bunch of them that you mount together, you can create an Automator script that will mount them for you, provided you know the share name for each. [I wrote about that option in an answer to another question back in October.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/automator-mount-a-network-volume/3308#3308)

Comment: I suspect, from bits of text I found while searching Google, that previous versions of OS X did in fact show the shares ending in a dollar sign. I would like to have the capability to list all shares, so that I don't have to remember them and don't need to clutter the bookmarks region with them.