# How to mount my MacBook's user folder as registered user using Automator?

Tags: automator, mount

In an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/3308/28268) to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/how-can-i-get-automator-to-mount-a-network-volume), [Ben Wyatt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1161/ben-wyatt) recommends the following to get Automator to mount a network volume:

> 1) Get Specified Servers. This will let you build a list of shares to connect to. If you can map it from Finder -> Go -> Connect to server, you can use this.
>
> 2) Connect to Servers. This will connect to any servers passed to it (either from get specified servers or from ask for servers).

In my case the network volume is my MacBook, and using Ben's method I'm only connected to the mounted volume as **guest**. But I need to be connected as a registered user.

I can of course specify a username and password in the server URL:

> afp://username:password@URLofMyMacBook

But then I get a window asking me to specify which volume I want to mount: Macintosh HD, my public folder, or my user folder?

**How can I get Automator to automatically mount my user folder?**

*I know I can create an alias of the mounted volume and probably get automator to "click" this, but I'd prefer to do this without having an extra file lying around.*

*And I want to do this with automator, not as a startup item, since I don't want to mount the volume upon startup.*

Answer (score 1):

Okay, problem was I thought of my user folder as residing in `/Users/userfolder` and the URL to that folder being `afp://URLofMyMacBook/Users/userfolder`.

But to connect directly to my userfolder I need to tell Automator to open:

> afp://username:password@URLofMyMacBook/userfolder

without `/Users/` in between. Now it works without asking me to specify the volume.

I found this out by mounting the volume manually and looking at the "Information" (Command+I).