# How do I get Samba volume to mount automatically at bootup?

Tags: smb, macos, automount

I have a windows share that I can mount via Connect to Server (⌘K in the finder)

```
smb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/SHARENAME
```

It there a way to have this volume mount automatically at bootup?

Comment: Like this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070202190047133 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using the applescript

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "smb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/SHARENAME"
        delay 1
    end try
end tell
```

that I found at: [How can I get automator...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/how-can-i-get-automator-to-mount-a-network-volume)

Saved as an application and then run via Login Items in the System Prefs.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add the alias as a Login item: go to System Preferences > Users & Groups, and click on Login Items. You can then drag a mounted network drive, or a drive alias, into the Login Items list.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty cool.  What is the earliest iOS to allow this?